# Как выйти из программы при условии ввода слова пользователем?

Tags: c++

Ниже представлен код, задача заключается в том, чтобы по команде, к примеру, `exit`, консоль закрывалась и никак иначе. "Побаловался" с калькулятором, надоело, решил выйти из консоли, закрыв её, фразой `exit`. Помогите мне это сделать, пожалуйста, я пытался изобразить это через `while`, но команда не работает:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    char o;

    do
    {
        cout << "Выполните действие" << endl;

        float x, y, z;

        char q;

        cin >> x;
        cin >> q;
        cin >> y;

        switch (q)
        {
        case '^': z = pow(x, y);
            break;
        case '+': (z = x + y);
            break;
        case '-': (z = x - y);
            break;
        case '/': (z = x / y);
            break;
        case '*': (z = x * y);
            break;
        }

        cout << (z) << endl;

        cin >> o;

    } while (o != 'exit');

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) если хотите ввести "exit", то переменная o должна быть строковой, не char

2) после считывания cin >> o; добавьте проверку

```
if(o == "exit")
   exit(0);
```

Comment: Уточню,  строковая - это string, а не  char *,  ну или не == а strcmp.

Comment: @pavel: для ясности: для [`std::string` следует использовать `==`](http://ideone.com/tVBLrT); для [`char*` можно использовать `strcmp()`](http://ideone.com/RTLfiK).